failing pxeboot install for 24.04 Server LTS
I'm trying to set up a pxeboot installer for 24.04 Server LTS. The machine finds our PXE and TFTP just fine, and loads the kernel and initrd. But when it gets to the install, it fails to recognize that it's received a DHCP address. I can tail the logs on our DHCP server and see it getting an address. On the console of the machine, I can see it naming that same IP address but then saying "no such device" and then "no devices to configure" despite starting each round with the IP it was assigned.
I've tried changing the pxeboot settings to use a static IP and still get errors along the lines of "no device." It tries a number of times at increasingly longer intervals and eventually fails out.
It seems to be that the BIOS can find a NIC for the initial boot but the kernel loaded via TFTP can't. Except I can still see each attempt in the logs on the DHCP server.
The machine is a VM running under the xen hypervisor. That doesn't seem like it should be an issue. It does work fine with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. In xen the default "NIC" is a Realtek or you can also choose to emulate an Intel e1000. I've tried both with no change. Update: I've also tried this on bare metal (Dell R740) with slightly different errors (the Dell is running UEFI and the VM uses legacy BIOS) but still no love.
Once it drops to the busybox/initramfs prompt, the network interface is unconfigured. I can enable it and it gets DHCP settings just fine including IP, GW, broadcast, DNS, TFTP server. DNS doesn't work, though: /etc/resolv.conf is empty. I can add a nameserver to it manually and then networking is fine. Here's a screenshot of the whole situation:

Has anything changed about calling the install from pxelinux.cfg.default?
Here's what I'm calling:
LABEL Ubuntu24.04 LTS Auto Install
  MENU LABEL Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Unattended Base Build (SCHARP)
  KERNEL ubuntu24.04/vmlinuz
  APPEND autoinstall initrd=ubuntu24.04/initrd root=/dev/ram0 ramdisk_size=16384 hostname=ubuntu-24 ip=dhcp url=http://depot.pc.scharp.org/ISO/ubuntu-24.04-live-server-amd64.iso ds=nocloud-et;s=http://depot.pc.scharp.org/auto_os/u24/

Update 4/29: It occurred to me I was using a very old version of the pxelinux.0 file. Installed pxelinux to my tfptd server and copied in current versions of pxelinux.0 and the dependent files. No change.
Also tried booting the install using static addressing, specifying the network device and settings in the "APPEND" line. I still get "no such device" in the error output despite seeing the same device name earlier.

Are you providing the PXE settings by ProxyDHCP or DHCP options?  I've seen similar behavior when using ProxyDHCP.  I see you posted a solution, but I don't see how cloud-config-url would cause this.

This was an issue with the pxeboot menu files pxelinux.cfg/default and grub.cfg. For both files, the kernel arguments line needed an entry specified that I've found little mention of other than saying it should be set to /dev/null. In general these arguments seem to be documented vaguely and in some cases, incorrectly.
Anyway, here's what works. I'll post the complete entries as they only contain private IP spaces and nameserver zones.
For pxelinux.cfg/default (legacy BIOS):
LABEL Ubuntu24.04LTS Auto Install
    MENU LABEL Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Unattended Base Build (SCHARP)
    KERNEL ubuntu24.04/vmlinuz
    APPEND initrd=ubuntu24.04/initrd ip=dhcp fsck.mode=skip url=http://depot.pc.scharp.org/ISO/ubuntu-24.04-live-server-amd64.iso autoinstall ds=nocloud-net;s=http://depot.pc.scharp.org/auto_os/u24/ cloud-config-url=http://depot.pc.scharp.org/auto_os/u24/user-data

For grub.cfg (UEFI):
menuentry "Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Auto Install" {
    echo "loading kernel..."
    linux ubuntu24.04/vmlinuz fsck.mode=skip autoinstall ip=dhcp url=http://depot.pc.scharp.org/ISO/ubuntu-24.04-live-server-amd64.iso ds=nocloud-net s=http://depot.pc.scharp.org/auto_os/u24/ cloud-config-url=http://depot.pc.scharp.org/auto_os/u24/user-data
    echo "loading RAM disk..."
    initrd ubuntu24.04/initrd
}

In general I'm a fan of not messing with defaults unless they need messing with. For example, I inherited the first menu entries listed earlier in this thread that hard-coded the boot disk location and size and hostname. This solution may well be hard-coding something that shouldn't need to be specified. But I'll take it.

I have the same problem. The initrd in the stable installation image is broken (the development image was working well). Getting DNS address from DHCP is not working. I tried both live-server and desktop image (the first stable release).
The solution is to wait for developers to fix it or not to use DHCP and set the IP and DNS manually in PXE boot file using the following format (instead of ip=dhcp):
ip=<client-ip>:<server-ip>:<gw-ip>:<netmask>:<hostname>:<device>:<autoconf>:<dns0-ip>:<dns1-ip>:<ntp0-ip>

Taken from this documentation - https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/nfs/nfsroot.txt
For me it worked.
